# How to prevent this libpods thing from added to project

Tags: react-native, fastlane

When I'm trying to build a CI/CD pipeline using, It come to an error "library not found for -lPods-APP NAME"

It's because the libpods-(APP NAME) was added during pod install. After I remove it, the build was successful.
But my target is to build in non-interactive mode, so is there any way to prevent it added or remove that damn thing by command line?
[The god dame libpod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97ACR.png)